# PHP mail() function polish diacritical marks

Tags: php, email

I was wondering how I can allow this following script with mail() function to run with diacritical marks used in polish letters like: ą, ś, ć, ź, ż etc.

The trouble is that somehow the title of email received is completely fine, where's the actual email content is not handling polish letters at all.

```
<?php
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-2\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$receiver = "testmail@gmail.com"; 
$title = "Title in polish - Przykładowy tekst wiadomości mail"; 
$message = "Ąą, Ćć, Ęę, Łł, Ńń, Óó, Śś, Żż, Źź"; 
$from = "myemail@mydomain.com"; 
$header = "From: " .$from; 

mail($receiver, $title, $message, $header); 
echo "Ok!"; 
?>
```

Comment: what if you use `utf-8`  instead `charset=ISO-8859-2`

Comment: already tried it, didn't work at all

Comment: 1) Is your php file UTF-8 or ISO-8859-2 encoded? 2) Could you post message **received** in "raw" format? 3) I personally recommend  using UTF-8 unless you **KNOW** what makes ISO-8859-2 better **in your case**.

Answer (score 1):

you have sent $header in mail function which excludes $headers contents.

Answer (score -1):

PHP mail() function you can try

```
// Code without trick
$subject = "I Love You ❤";

// You will end up with junk character in subject
mail("email@receiver.com",$subject,"This email subject will contain JUNK characters.");


// Code with trick
$subject = "I Love You ❤";
$updated_subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=";

mail("email@receiver.com",$updated_subject,"This email subject should not contain JUNK characters.")
```

follow [this link](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2013/05/set-unicode-character-in-email-subject-php/)